# can I debug compiled static libraries in ios development

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, static-libraries

I want to be able to step through code whether it steps into my own static library or not.. if I can't do this, I'm just going to link the code into XCode. Static Libraries make me warm and fuzzy from a 'clean' architecture point of view but if I can't debug through them when the execution enters them I don't want to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xcode 4 Preview offers this debugging feature if you have the source to that library (and, I think you ought to add it as a sub-project). In Xcode 3, you will likely need to make the library sources a part of the main app project.

Comment: If you have the source to that library *and* the library was compiled with debugging enabled.

Comment: I might as well just link the source code directly into the project and forget the whole static library thing then eh? P.S. XCode 4 is now golden master ;)